# ADD TO BASKET - How to add a key value pair php

Tags: php

So I am able to add to a basket, but I want to keep a key-value pair so that when I click on "add to basket", it adds the product and its quantity.

So I have this button on my products page:

```
 <a href='add.php?id={$row["productID"]}&stock=9'><button class='btn btn-success'>Add</button></a>
```

This is the code for just adding the product to the basket:

```
 <?php
session_start();

$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "";
$quantity = isset($_GET['quantity']) ? $_GET['quantity'] : "";


if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_items'])){
    $_SESSION['cart_items'] = array();
    $_SESSION['cart_items'][$id]=$name;
}
    header('Location: product.php?action=added&id' . $id . '&quantity=' . $quantity);
}
?>
```

Then on the basket page I am able to retrieve just the product like this:

```
 foreach($_SESSION['cart_items'] as $id=>$value){
     $ids = $ids . $id . ",";
     echo $ids;
 }
```

Only problem is how do I do for quantity as well as I need to link the quantity to the product?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you could add up another dimension into your Session Array, something like this,

```
$_SESSION['cart_items'][$id]    = array("name"=>$name, "qty"=>$quantity);
```

and while retrieving you could use it as follows.

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart_items'] as $id=>$value){
     echo "Id = ".$id." | Name = ".$value["name"]." | Qty : ".$value["qty"]."<br>";
 }
```

**Updating Quantity :**

just simply overwrite the dimension : `$_SESSION['cart_items']["productId"]["qty"] = "updated Qty";`

Comment: what about updating the value?

Comment: How do I refer to it like a key-value though?

Comment: @TimShadz, when you define a key, you have full control to modify the values using those keys. the idea is to, temporarily feed info of products and qtys, you can easily dump, modify and retrieve.